# Fourier series with fractional linear transformation of argument

Tags: fourier-analysis, modular-group

Set as usual $e(z):=\exp(2\pi iz)$. Having two series that are related for all $z$ in the upper halfplane via a transformation formula
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\alpha_n e\Big(n\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\Big)}=p(z)+q(z)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\beta_n e(nz)}
$$
where $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are polynomials and $ad-bc=1$, can I deduce some relation between $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$?